# How can we do paging with backbone marionette composite view?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, paging, backbone.paginator

I am new to backbone and marionette. Now i m trying to implement paging with compositeview of marionettejs. Below is my code, what happens here that when a new fetch is done through my custom pager, existing data is getting replaced by new set of data instead of appending. Please help me to overcome this! Thanks in advance.

```
 define(['text!/Templates/projects/_GroupItem.html', 'collections/projects/groups'], function (ProjectGroupsTmpl, GroupCollection) {
    var GroupItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        template: _.template(ProjectGroupsTmpl) 
    });
    var CompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        template: _.template("<ul id='ulgroups' ></ul>"),
        itemView: GroupItemView,
        itemViewContainer: '#ulgroups',
        initialize: function (params) {
            this.isLoading = false; 
            this.ProjectID = params.id;
            this.collection = new GroupCollection();
            this.getData();
            var self = this;
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                self.checkScroll();
            });
        },
        getData: function () { 
            var that = this;
            this.isLoading = true;
            this.collection.fetch({ 
                data: { ProjectID: this.ProjectID },
                success: function (collection, response, options) { 
                    that.isLoading = false;
                }
            });
        },
        checkScroll: function () { 
            var triggerPoint = 100; // 100px from the bottom 
            if (!this.isLoading && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + triggerPoint > $(document).height()) { 
                this.collection.page += 1; // Load next page 
                this.getData();
            }
        },
        appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView, index) {            
            $(this.itemViewContainer).append(itemView.el);
        }
    });
    return CompositeView;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [backbone.paginator](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator) to resolve above issue and it works well. Below are the new code used for that.

**Collection:**

```
   define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'helper',
  'paginator'
], function ($, _, Backbone) {
    var Groups = Backbone.PageableCollection.extend({
        url: 'projects/_groups',
        mode: "infinite",
        state: {
            pageSize: null 
        },
        queryParams: {
            totalPages: null,
            totalRecords: null 
        }
    });
    return Groups;
});
```

**Marionette CompositeView:**

```
define(['text!/Templates/projects/_GroupItem.html', 'collections/projects/groups'], function (ProjectGroupsTmpl, GroupCollection) {
    var GroupItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        template: _.template(ProjectGroupsTmpl)
    });
    var CompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        template: _.template("<ul id='ulgroups' ></ul>"),
        itemView: GroupItemView,
        itemViewContainer: '#ulgroups',
        initialize: function (params) {
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.ProjectID = params.id;
            this.grpcollection = new GroupCollection([], {
                queryParams: {
                    ProjectID: params.id
                }
            });
            this.collection = this.grpcollection.fullCollection;
            this.getData();
            var self = this;
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                self.checkScroll();
            });
        },
        getData: function () {
            var that = this;
            this.isLoading = true;
            this.grpcollection.fetch({
                success: function (collection, response, options) {
                    if (response.length > 0) {
                        that.isLoading = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        getNextPage: function () {
            var that = this;
            this.isLoading = true;
            this.grpcollection.getNextPage({
                success: function (collection, response, options) {
                    if (response.length > 0) {
                        that.isLoading = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        checkScroll: function () {
            var triggerPoint = 100; // 100px from the bottom 
            if (!this.isLoading && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + triggerPoint > $(document).height()) {
                this.getNextPage();
            }
        },
        appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView, index) {
            $(this.itemViewContainer).append(itemView.el);
        }
    });
    return CompositeView;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem recently by creating a temporary collection to hold the models for each paginated request. My setup was slightly different to yours, however, in that I created a Marionette controller to negotiate between the data and the view. A "show" method on the controller handled the initial data request and a "showMore" method handled subsequent requests. Here is basically what I did:

```
(function ($, _, Backbone, Marionette) {
    var carData = [
        {
            make: 'Audi',
            model: 'A4',
            year: '1994'
        },
        {
            make: 'BMW',
            model: '3 Series',
            year: '1975'
        },
        {
            make: 'Chevrolet',
            model: 'Cruze',
            year: '2008'
        },
        {
            make: 'Daimler',
            model: 'Six',
            year: '1994'
        },
        {
            make: 'Fiat',
            model: '500X',
            year: '2015'
        },
        {
            make: 'Honda',
            model: 'Civic',
            year: '1972'
        },
        {
            make: 'Kia',
            model: 'Optima',
            year: '2015'
        },
        {
            make: 'Lada',
            model: 'Priora',
            year: '2007'
        },
        {
            make: 'Mitusbishi',
            model: 'Lancer',
            year: '1973'
        },
        {
            make: 'Nissan',
            model: 'Pathfinder',
            year: '1995'
        }
    ];
    var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            make: '',
            model: '',
            year: ''
        }
    });
    var Cars = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Car,
        rows: 3,
        page: 0
    });
    var CarView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: 'tr',
        template: '#row-template'
    });
    var CarsView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        childView: CarView,
        childViewContainer: 'tbody',
        template: '#table-template',
        triggers: {
            'click button': 'showMore'
        }
    });
    var CarController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
        initialize: function (options) {
            this.collection = options.collection;
        },
        show: function () {
            var cars = this.getData(this.collection.page);
            var carsView = new CarsView({
                collection: new Backbone.Collection(cars)
            });
            this.listenTo(carsView, 'showMore', this.showMore);
            app.carsRegion.show(carsView);
        },
        showMore: function (options) {
            var cars = this.getData(++this.collection.page);
            options.collection.add(cars);
        },
        getData: function (page) {
            var rows = this.collection.rows;
            var start = page * rows;
            var end = start + rows;
            return this.collection.slice(start, end);

        }
    });
    var app = new Marionette.Application();
    var cars = new Cars(carData);
    var carController = new CarController({
        collection: cars
    });
    app.addRegions({
        carsRegion: '#cars-region'
    });
    app.addInitializer(function () {
        carController.show();
    });
    app.start();
}(jQuery, _, Backbone, Marionette));
```

This is also available as a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/david_i_smith/wuLLc7dw/).

Comment: Thanks smith, but do you have suggestion if want to fetch collection inside the view itself?

Comment: You could still fetch models from the master collection (GroupCollection). It's just that you would be adding the relevant models from each fetch to a temporary collection. The temporary collection would start out as empty and be added to with each new "pull" for data. Make sense? Having said this I'd still recommend creating a controller to manage the data requests and view creation. Makes for a cleaner separation of concerns IMO.